# Absolute value of a martingale

Tags: probability, inequality, stochastic-processes, martingales

Given a martingale $M(t)$, can I use Doob's inequality on $|M(t)|$ to achieve the following upper bond?
$$P(\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}|M(t)|>\epsilon)=P(\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}|M(t)|^2>\epsilon^2)\leq\frac{E[|M(T)|^2]}{\epsilon^2}.$$
My reasoning is that since $M(t)$ is a martingale, both $|M(t)|$ and $|M(t)|^2$ are ones too.

Comment: $M$ being a martingale does certainly **not** imply that $|M|$ and $|M|^2$ are martingales.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. In what cases, then, am I able to make that conclusion?

Comment: Always; I'm just saying that your reasoning is not correct.

Comment: I've just re-read what I wrote. Would it be correct if I switched that word with sub-martingales? It is what I was actually trying to say, sorry

Comment: Yes, submartingale is the good notion here.

Comment: Note that the maps $x\mapsto |x|$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ are concave, and hence $|M(t)|$ and $M(t)^2$ are submartingales by Jensen's inequality.